# php mail function is not working

Tags: php

My mail function was disabled, i asked hosting to enable it. 
Now my mail function is not producing any warning. It is saying that email sent successfully. But Email is not sending.

i tried it even simple mail function. But it is not working.

Comment: Are you using any libraries (PHPMailer for example). They usually have some debug option. Also, check your spamfolder.

Comment: Check your junk or spam. it should be sending.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest creating a blank .php document with a simple mail sending function on it. If this does not work I would recommend that you contact your hosting provider as it could be another issue with their setup.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the hosting again, I faced this once and my hosting had badly configured [sendmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sendmail) path.